# VBA: using index and match with two columns as criterias (INCOMPATIBLE VARIABLE ERROR)

Tags: vba, indexing, match

I'm trying to implement an index+match formula by using two columns as refereces to get a third column.

I have the following table and the code. 
any suggestions?

`billy  FESTO   1
billy   FELIPE  2
billy   JOHNY   3
billy   MARCO   4
billy   TOS     5
john    CASTRO  6
billy   CAM     7
billy   THR     8
billy   SIS     9
billy   VIX    10
billy   KOX    11
billy   JUH    12
billy   MIL    13
billy   MIS    14
billy   MR    15
billy   MAN   16`

```
`  Sub test()
   Dim teste As String

   teste = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("C1:C100"), 
   WorksheetFunction.Match("billy" & "&" & "TOS", Range("A1:A100") _
   & "&" & Range("B1:B100"), 0))

   End Sub
```

Comment: I tried by using the code mentioned in the other post, but didn't get correct responde, its occuring an incompatible variable type error.